# LIBVLC Android: Choppy and garbled sound from audio stream (HTTP)

Tags: android, audio, stream, libvlc

I've just made an AV HTTP streamer using the LIBVLC 2.0.6 and the player works just fine, but for some of my audio streams, I only get a choppy garbled sound with no audio. When I play the same stream on a VLC media player, it works fine.

**VideoPlayerActivity.java**

```
public class VideoPlayerActivity extends Activity implements MediaPlayer.EventListener, IVLCVout.Callback, SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {

......

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ArrayList<String> options = new ArrayList<>();
    options.add("network-caching=300");
    options.add("-vvv"); // verbosity

    try {
        libVLC = new LibVLC(getApplicationContext(), options);
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onCreate: " + e);
        finish();
    }

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_player);

    String url = getIntent().getStringExtra(Constants.URL);
   ........

    surfaceView = (SurfaceView) mContentView;
    SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
    surfaceHolder.setKeepScreenOn(true);

    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(libVLC);
    mediaPlayer.setEventListener(this);

    iVLCVout = mediaPlayer.getVLCVout();
    iVLCVout.addCallback(this);
    iVLCVout.setVideoView(surfaceView);
    iVLCVout.attachViews();

    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: " + Uri.parse(url));

    try {
        mediaPlayer.setMedia(new Media(libVLC, Uri.parse(url)));
        mediaPlayer.play();
        mediaPlayer.setVolume(100);
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onCreate: " + e);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Invalid link!!! Contact operator!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
..................
```

Here is the the log when I play the audio stream (faulty ones):

```
02-15 20:03:41.002 3832-3950/tv.redtop D/PlayActivity: startPlayback: mime type is: video/x-matroska
02-15 20:03:41.450 3832-3832/tv.redtop D/VLC: [aa4b3508/ef8] core input: Creating an input for '1592986332?ticket=3BD753B66495441C59566BC7CC80948F93EAE8D6&mux=matroska'
02-15 20:03:41.452 3832-4647/tv.redtop D/VLC: [aa4b3508/1227] core input: using timeshift granularity of 50 MiB
02-15 20:03:41.460 3832-4647/tv.redtop D/VLC: [aa4b3508/1227] core input: using default timeshift path
02-15 20:03:41.461 3832-4647/tv.redtop D/VLC: [aa4b3508/1227] core input: `http://user:pass@myredtop.info:5555/stream/channelid/1592986332?ticket=3BD753B66495441C59566BC7CC80948F93EAE8D6&mux=matroska' gives access `http' demux `' path `user:pass@myredtop.info:5555/stream/channelid/1592986332?ticket=3BD753B66495441C59566BC7CC80948F93EAE8D6&mux=matroska'
02-15 20:03:41.461 3832-4647/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9aebf028/1227] core input source: specified demux: any
02-15 20:03:41.461 3832-4647/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9aebf028/1227] core input source: creating demux: access='http' demux='any' location='user:pass@myredtop.info:5555/stream/channelid/1592986332?ticket=3BD753B66495441C59566BC7CC80948F93EAE8D6&mux=matroska&vlc=rulez' file='(null)'
02-15 20:03:41.461 3832-4647/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9b3d0f28/1227] core demux: looking for access_demux module matching "http": 6 candidates
02-15 20:03:41.461 3832-4647/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9b3d0f28/1227] core demux: no access_demux modules matched
02-15 20:03:41.461 3832-4647/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9b3d0fa8/1227] core access: creating access: http://user:pass@myredtop.info:5555/stream/channelid/1592986332?ticket=3BD753B66495441C59566BC7CC80948F93EAE8D6&mux=matroska&vlc=rulez
02-15 20:03:41.461 3832-4647/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9b3d0fa8/1227] core access: looking for access module matching "http": 23 candidates
02-15 20:03:41.463 3832-4648/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9b3d0fa8/1228] transport access: resolving myredtop.info ...
02-15 20:03:41.772 3832-4648/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9b3d0fa8/1228] transport access: connecting to myredtop.info port 5555 ...
02-15 20:03:41.952 3832-4647/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9b3d0fa8/1227] h1conn access: outgoing request:
                                              GET /stream/channelid/1592986332?ticket=3BD753B66495441C59566BC7CC80948F93EAE8D6&mux=matroska&vlc=rulez HTTP/1.1
                                              Host: myredtop.info:5555
                                              Accept: "*/*"
                                              Accept-Language: en_US
                                              User-Agent: VLC/3.0.0-git LibVLC/3.0.0-git
                                              Range: bytes=0-
02-15 20:03:42.153 3832-4647/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9b3d0fa8/1227] h1conn access: incoming response:
                                              HTTP/1.1 200 OK
                                              Server: HTS/tvheadend
                                              Cache-Control: no-cache
                                              Connection: Close
                                              Content-Type: audio/mp2t
02-15 20:03:42.153 3832-4647/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9b3d0fa8/1227] core access: using access module "access"
02-15 20:03:42.154 3832-4647/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9aec4028/1227] core stream: looking for stream_filter module matching "cache_block": 12 candidates
02-15 20:03:42.154 3832-4647/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9aec4028/1227] cache_block stream: Using block method for AStream*
02-15 20:03:42.154 3832-4647/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9aec4028/1227] cache_block stream: starting pre-buffering
02-15 20:03:42.162 3832-4647/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9aec4028/1227] cache_block stream: received first data after 7 ms
02-15 20:03:42.162 3832-4647/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9aec4028/1227] cache_block stream: prebuffering done 188 bytes in 0s - 23 KiB/s
02-15 20:03:42.162 3832-4647/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9aec4028/1227] core stream: using stream_filter module "cache_block"
02-15 20:03:42.162 3832-4647/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9aec40a8/1227] core stream: looking for stream_filter module matching "any": 12 candidates
02-15 20:03:42.162 3832-4647/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9aec40a8/1227] core stream: no stream_filter modules matched
02-15 20:03:42.162 3832-4647/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9aec40a8/1227] core stream: looking for stream_filter module matching "record": 12 candidates
02-15 20:03:42.162 3832-4647/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9aec40a8/1227] core stream: using stream_filter module "record"
02-15 20:03:42.162 3832-4647/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9aebf028/1227] core input source: creating demux: access='http' demux='any' location='user:pass@myredtop.info:5555/stream/channelid/1592986332?ticket=3BD753B66495441C59566BC7CC80948F93EAE8D6&mux=matroska&vlc=rulez' file='(null)'
02-15 20:03:42.162 3832-4647/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9aec4128/1227] core demux: looking for demux module matching "any": 61 candidates
02-15 20:03:42.163 3832-4647/tv.redtop D/VLC: [980114a8/1227] core xml reader: looking for xml reader module matching "any": 1 candidates
02-15 20:03:42.163 3832-4647/tv.redtop D/VLC: [980114a8/1227] core xml reader: using xml reader module "xml"
02-15 20:03:42.164 3832-4647/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9aec4128/1227] ts demux: Standard set to Auto
02-15 20:03:42.164 3832-4647/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9aec4128/1227] core demux: using demux module "ts"
02-15 20:03:42.165 3832-4647/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9aec4128/1227] ts demux: DEMUX_SET_GROUP 0 0x0
02-15 20:03:42.165 3832-4647/tv.redtop D/VLC: [aa4b3648/1227] core demux meta: looking for meta reader module matching "any": 2 candidates
02-15 20:03:42.166 3832-4647/tv.redtop D/VLC: [aa4b3648/1227] lua demux meta: Trying Lua scripts in /data/user/0/tv.redtop/app_vlc/.share/lua/meta/reader
02-15 20:03:42.166 3832-4647/tv.redtop D/VLC: [aa4b3648/1227] lua demux meta: Trying Lua scripts in /data/app/tv.redtop-2/lib/arm/vlc/lua/meta/reader
02-15 20:03:42.166 3832-4647/tv.redtop D/VLC: [aa4b3648/1227] lua demux meta: Trying Lua scripts in /data/app/tv.redtop-2/share/vlc/lua/meta/reader
02-15 20:03:42.166 3832-4647/tv.redtop D/VLC: [aa4b3648/1227] core demux meta: no meta reader modules matched
02-15 20:03:42.167 3832-4647/tv.redtop D/VLC: [aa4b3508/1227] core input: `http://user:pass@myredtop.info:5555/stream/channelid/1592986332?ticket=3BD753B66495441C59566BC7CC80948F93EAE8D6&mux=matroska&vlc=rulez' successfully opened
02-15 20:03:42.167 3832-4647/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9aec4128/1227] ts demux: pid[4095] unknown
02-15 20:03:42.167 3832-4647/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9aec4128/1227] ts demux: pid[257] unknown
02-15 20:03:42.168 3832-4647/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9aec4128/1227] ts demux: PATCallBack called
02-15 20:03:42.168 3832-4647/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9aec4128/1227] ts demux: new PAT ts_id=0 version=1 current_next=1
02-15 20:03:42.168 3832-4647/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9aec4128/1227] ts demux:   * number=1234 pid=1337
02-15 20:03:42.168 3832-4647/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9aec4128/1227] ts demux: temporary receiving program 1234
02-15 20:03:42.168 3832-4647/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9aec4128/1227] ts demux: PMTCallBack called for program 1234
02-15 20:03:42.168 3832-4647/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9aec4128/1227] ts demux: new PMT program number=1234 version=1 pid_pcr=257
02-15 20:03:42.168 3832-4647/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9aec4128/1227] ts demux:   * pid=257 type=0x4 ISO/IEC 13818-3 Audio
02-15 20:03:42.168 3832-4647/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9aec4128/1227] ts demux:    => pid 257 has now es fcc=mpga
02-15 20:03:42.168 3832-4647/tv.redtop D/VLC: [aa4b3508/1227] core input: selecting program id=1234
02-15 20:03:42.169 3832-4647/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9b3bdc28/1227] core packetizer: looking for packetizer module matching "any": 24 candidates
02-15 20:03:42.169 3832-4647/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9b3bdc28/1227] core packetizer: using packetizer module "mpeg_audio"
02-15 20:03:42.169 3832-4647/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9b3bd8a8/1227] core decoder: looking for decoder module matching "mediacodec_ndk,iomx,all": 39 candidates
02-15 20:03:42.169 3832-4647/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9b3bd8a8/1227] core decoder: using decoder module "mpeg_audio"
02-15 20:03:42.170 3832-4647/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9aec4128/1227] ts demux: Default program is 1234
02-15 20:03:42.170 3832-4647/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9aec4128/1227] ts demux: enabling pid 257 from program 1234
02-15 20:03:42.170 3832-4647/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9aec4128/1227] ts demux: enabling pcr pid 257 from program 1234
02-15 20:03:42.170 3832-4647/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9aec4128/1227] ts demux:   * pid=17 listening for SDT
02-15 20:03:42.170 3832-4647/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9aec4128/1227] ts demux: enabling pid 257 from program 1234
02-15 20:03:42.170 3832-4647/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9aec4128/1227] ts demux: enabling pcr pid 257 from program 1234
02-15 20:03:42.170 3832-4647/tv.redtop W/VLC: [9aec4128/1227] ts demux: first packet for pid=257 cc=0x1
02-15 20:03:42.171 3832-4647/tv.redtop D/VLC: [aa4b3508/1227] core input: Buffering 0%
02-15 20:03:42.171 3832-4647/tv.redtop W/VLC: [9aec4128/1227] ts demux: Broken stream: pid 257 sends packets with dts 888900us later than pcr, applying delay
02-15 20:03:42.171 3832-4647/tv.redtop D/VLC: [aa4b3508/1227] core input: Buffering 9%
02-15 20:03:42.172 3832-4671/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9b3bdc28/123f] mpeg_audio packetizer: emulated startcode
02-15 20:03:42.172 3832-4671/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9b3bdc28/123f] mpeg_audio packetizer: free bitrate mode
02-15 20:03:42.333 3832-4647/tv.redtop D/VLC: [aa4b3508/1227] core input: Buffering 18%
02-15 20:03:42.335 3832-4647/tv.redtop D/VLC: [aa4b3508/1227] core input: Buffering 27%
02-15 20:03:42.342 3832-4671/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9b3bdc28/123f] mpeg_audio packetizer: frame too big 2509 > 2508 (emulated startcode ?)
02-15 20:03:42.342 3832-4671/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9b3bdc28/123f] mpeg_audio packetizer: emulated startcode
02-15 20:03:42.343 3832-4647/tv.redtop D/VLC: [aa4b3508/1227] core input: Buffering 37%
02-15 20:03:42.343 3832-4671/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9b3bdc28/123f] mpeg_audio packetizer: emulated startcode
02-15 20:03:42.343 3832-4647/tv.redtop D/VLC: [aa4b3508/1227] core input: Buffering 46%
02-15 20:03:42.343 3832-4671/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9b3bdc28/123f] mpeg_audio packetizer: emulated startcode
02-15 20:03:42.344 3832-4647/tv.redtop D/VLC: [aa4b3508/1227] core input: Buffering 55%
02-15 20:03:42.344 3832-4671/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9b3bdc28/123f] mpeg_audio packetizer: emulated startcode
02-15 20:03:42.345 3832-4647/tv.redtop D/VLC: [aa4b3508/1227] core input: Buffering 65%
02-15 20:03:42.345 3832-4671/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9b3bdc28/123f] mpeg_audio packetizer: emulated startcode
02-15 20:03:42.345 3832-4647/tv.redtop D/VLC: [aa4b3508/1227] core input: Buffering 74%
02-15 20:03:42.346 3832-4671/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9b3bdc28/123f] mpeg_audio packetizer: emulated startcode
02-15 20:03:42.346 3832-4671/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9b3bdc28/123f] mpeg_audio packetizer: free bitrate mode
02-15 20:03:42.346 3832-4647/tv.redtop D/VLC: [aa4b3508/1227] core input: Buffering 83%
02-15 20:03:42.346 3832-4647/tv.redtop D/VLC: [aa4b3508/1227] core input: Buffering 92%
02-15 20:03:42.347 3832-4671/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9b3bdc28/123f] mpeg_audio packetizer: frame too big 2509 > 2508 (emulated startcode ?)
02-15 20:03:42.347 3832-4671/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9b3bdc28/123f] mpeg_audio packetizer: emulated startcode
02-15 20:03:42.347 3832-4647/tv.redtop D/VLC: [aa4b3508/1227] core input: Stream buffering done (1532 ms in 176 ms)
02-15 20:03:42.347 3832-4671/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9b3bdc28/123f] mpeg_audio packetizer: emulated startcode
02-15 20:03:42.347 3832-4647/tv.redtop E/VLC: [9b3bd8a8/1227] core decoder: buffer deadlock prevented
02-15 20:03:42.347 3832-4647/tv.redtop D/VLC: [aa4b3508/1227] core input: Decoder wait done in 0 ms
02-15 20:03:42.569 3832-4671/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9b3bdc28/123f] mpeg_audio packetizer: emulated startcode
02-15 20:03:42.709 3832-4671/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9b3bdc28/123f] mpeg_audio packetizer: emulated startcode (no startcode on following frame)
02-15 20:03:42.709 3832-4671/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9b3bdc28/123f] mpeg_audio packetizer: free bitrate mode
02-15 20:03:43.126 3832-4671/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9b3bdc28/123f] mpeg_audio packetizer: frame too big 2509 > 2508 (emulated startcode ?)
02-15 20:03:43.126 3832-4671/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9b3bdc28/123f] mpeg_audio packetizer: emulated startcode
02-15 20:03:43.127 3832-4671/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9b3bdc28/123f] mpeg_audio packetizer: free bitrate mode
02-15 20:03:43.266 3832-4671/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9b3bdc28/123f] mpeg_audio packetizer: frame too big 1443 > 1442 (emulated startcode ?)
02-15 20:03:43.266 3832-4671/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9b3bdc28/123f] mpeg_audio packetizer: emulated startcode
02-15 20:03:43.266 3832-4671/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9b3bdc28/123f] mpeg_audio packetizer: free bitrate mode
02-15 20:03:43.406 3832-4671/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9b3bdc28/123f] mpeg_audio packetizer: MPGA channels:2 samplerate:44100 bitrate:0
02-15 20:03:43.407 3832-4671/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9b3bd8a8/123f] core decoder: restarting module due to input format change
02-15 20:03:43.407 3832-4671/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9b3bd8a8/123f] core decoder: removing module "mpeg_audio"
02-15 20:03:43.408 3832-4671/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9b3bd8a8/123f] core decoder: looking for decoder module matching "mediacodec_ndk,iomx,all": 39 candidates
02-15 20:03:43.410 3832-4671/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9b3bd8a8/123f] core decoder: using decoder module "mpeg_audio"
02-15 20:03:43.410 3832-4671/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9b3bd8a8/123f] mpeg_audio decoder: free bitrate mode
02-15 20:03:43.823 3832-4671/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9b3bdc28/123f] mpeg_audio packetizer: frame too big 2509 > 2508 (emulated startcode ?)
02-15 20:03:43.823 3832-4671/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9b3bdc28/123f] mpeg_audio packetizer: emulated startcode
02-15 20:03:44.102 3832-4671/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9b3bdc28/123f] mpeg_audio packetizer: emulated startcode (no startcode on following frame)
02-15 20:03:48.207 3832-4647/tv.redtop E/VLC: [9aec4128/1227] ts demux: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS duplicate (received 0, expected 1) for PID 0
02-15 20:03:48.207 3832-4671/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9b3bdc28/123f] mpeg_audio packetizer: emulated startcode
02-15 20:03:48.208 3832-4671/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9b3bdc28/123f] mpeg_audio packetizer: emulated startcode
02-15 20:03:48.208 3832-4647/tv.redtop E/VLC: [aa4b3508/1227] core input: ES_OUT_SET_(GROUP_)PCR  is called too late (pts_delay increased to 1500 ms)
02-15 20:03:48.208 3832-4671/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9b3bdc28/123f] mpeg_audio packetizer: emulated startcode
02-15 20:03:48.208 3832-4647/tv.redtop D/VLC: [aa4b3508/1227] core input: ES_OUT_RESET_PCR called
02-15 20:03:48.209 3832-4647/tv.redtop W/VLC: [9aec4128/1227] ts demux: discontinuity received 0x0 instead of 0x9 (pid=257)
02-15 20:03:48.209 3832-4671/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9b3bdc28/123f] mpeg_audio packetizer: emulated startcode
02-15 20:03:48.210 3832-4647/tv.redtop D/VLC: [aa4b3508/1227] core input: Buffering 0%
02-15 20:03:48.211 3832-4671/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9b3bdc28/123f] mpeg_audio packetizer: emulated startcode
02-15 20:03:48.212 3832-4647/tv.redtop D/VLC: [aa4b3508/1227] core input: Buffering 9%
02-15 20:03:48.213 3832-4671/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9b3bdc28/123f] mpeg_audio packetizer: emulated startcode
02-15 20:03:48.214 3832-4647/tv.redtop D/VLC: [aa4b3508/1227] core input: Buffering 18%
02-15 20:03:48.214 3832-4671/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9b3bdc28/123f] mpeg_audio packetizer: emulated startcode
02-15 20:03:48.215 3832-4671/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9b3bdc28/123f] mpeg_audio packetizer: free bitrate mode
02-15 20:03:48.216 3832-4647/tv.redtop D/VLC: [aa4b3508/1227] core input: Buffering 27%
02-15 20:03:48.218 3832-4647/tv.redtop D/VLC: [aa4b3508/1227] core input: Buffering 37%
02-15 20:03:48.219 3832-4647/tv.redtop D/VLC: [aa4b3508/1227] core input: Buffering 46%
02-15 20:03:48.219 3832-4671/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9b3bd8a8/123f] mpeg_audio decoder: free bitrate mode
02-15 20:03:48.220 3832-4647/tv.redtop D/VLC: [aa4b3508/1227] core input: Buffering 55%
02-15 20:03:48.222 3832-4647/tv.redtop D/VLC: [aa4b3508/1227] core input: Buffering 65%
02-15 20:03:48.223 3832-4647/tv.redtop D/VLC: [aa4b3508/1227] core input: Buffering 74%
02-15 20:03:48.224 3832-4647/tv.redtop D/VLC: [aa4b3508/1227] core input: Buffering 83%
02-15 20:03:48.225 3832-4671/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9b3bdc28/123f] mpeg_audio packetizer: frame too big 2509 > 2508 (emulated startcode ?)
02-15 20:03:48.225 3832-4671/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9b3bdc28/123f] mpeg_audio packetizer: emulated startcode
02-15 20:03:48.225 3832-4671/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9b3bdc28/123f] mpeg_audio packetizer: free bitrate mode
02-15 20:03:48.225 3832-4647/tv.redtop D/VLC: [aa4b3508/1227] core input: Buffering 92%
02-15 20:03:48.226 3832-4671/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9b3bdc28/123f] mpeg_audio packetizer: frame too big 2509 > 2508 (emulated startcode ?)
02-15 20:03:48.226 3832-4647/tv.redtop D/VLC: [aa4b3508/1227] core input: Stream buffering done (1532 ms in 15 ms)
02-15 20:03:48.226 3832-4671/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9b3bdc28/123f] mpeg_audio packetizer: emulated startcode
02-15 20:03:48.227 3832-4671/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9b3bdc28/123f] mpeg_audio packetizer: free bitrate mode
02-15 20:03:48.228 3832-4671/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9b3bd8a8/123f] mpeg_audio decoder: MPGA channels:2 samplerate:44100 bitrate:0
02-15 20:03:48.228 3832-4671/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9a49b078/123f] core generic: reusing audio output
02-15 20:03:48.229 3832-4671/tv.redtop D/VLC: [98056fe8/123f] core audio output: VLC is looking for: 'mpga' 44100 Hz Stereo frame=1152 samples/2516 bytes
02-15 20:03:48.257 3832-4671/tv.redtop D/AudioTrack: Client defaulted notificationFrames to 4810 for frameCount 9620
02-15 20:03:48.260 3832-4671/tv.redtop D/VLC: [98056fe8/123f] android_audiotrack audio output: using WRITE_BYTEBUFFER
02-15 20:03:48.483 3832-4671/tv.redtop D/VLC: [98056fe8/123f] core audio output: VLC will output: 's16l' 48000 Hz Stereo frame=1152 samples/2516 bytes
02-15 20:03:48.483 3832-4671/tv.redtop D/VLC: [98056fe8/123f] core audio output: output 's16l' 48000 Hz Stereo frame=1 samples/4 bytes
02-15 20:03:48.483 3832-4671/tv.redtop D/VLC: [acc05fe8/123f] core volume: looking for audio volume module matching "any": 3 candidates
02-15 20:03:48.483 3832-4671/tv.redtop D/VLC: [acc05fe8/123f] core volume: using audio volume module "integer_mixer"
02-15 20:03:48.483 3832-4671/tv.redtop D/VLC: [98056fe8/123f] core audio output: input 'mpga' 44100 Hz Stereo frame=1152 samples/2516 bytes
02-15 20:03:48.484 3832-4671/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9b3c02a8/123f] core audio filter: looking for audio filter module matching "scaletempo": 13 candidates
02-15 20:03:48.484 3832-4671/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9b3c02a8/123f] scaletempo audio filter: format: 44100 rate, 2 nch, 4 bps, fl32
02-15 20:03:48.484 3832-4671/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9b3c02a8/123f] scaletempo audio filter: params: 30 stride, 0.200 overlap, 14 search
02-15 20:03:48.484 3832-4671/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9b3c02a8/123f] scaletempo audio filter: 1.000 scale, 1323.000 stride_in, 1323 stride_out, 1059 standing, 264 overlap, 617 search, 2204 queue, fl32 mode
02-15 20:03:48.484 3832-4671/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9b3c02a8/123f] core audio filter: using audio filter module "scaletempo"
02-15 20:03:48.484 3832-4671/tv.redtop D/VLC: [98056fe8/123f] core audio output: conversion: 'mpga'->'f32l' 44100 Hz->44100 Hz Stereo->Stereo
02-15 20:03:48.484 3832-4671/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9b3bff28/123f] core audio converter: looking for audio converter module matching "any": 9 candidates
02-15 20:03:48.484 3832-4671/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9b3bff28/123f] core audio converter: no audio converter modules matched
02-15 20:03:48.484 3832-4671/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9b3bff28/123f] core audio converter: looking for audio converter module matching "any": 9 candidates
02-15 20:03:48.484 3832-4671/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9b3bff28/123f] mad audio converter: mpga->f32l, bits per sample: 32
02-15 20:03:48.484 3832-4671/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9b3bff28/123f] core audio converter: using audio converter module "mad"
02-15 20:03:48.484 3832-4671/tv.redtop D/VLC: [98056fe8/123f] core audio output: conversion pipeline complete
02-15 20:03:48.484 3832-4671/tv.redtop D/VLC: [98056fe8/123f] core audio output: conversion: 'f32l'->'s16l' 44100 Hz->44100 Hz Stereo->Stereo
02-15 20:03:48.485 3832-4671/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9b3bfba8/123f] core audio converter: looking for audio converter module matching "any": 9 candidates
02-15 20:03:48.485 3832-4671/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9b3bfba8/123f] audio_format audio converter: f32l->s16l, bits per sample: 0->16
02-15 20:03:48.485 3832-4671/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9b3bfba8/123f] core audio converter: using audio converter module "audio_format"
02-15 20:03:48.485 3832-4671/tv.redtop D/VLC: [98056fe8/123f] core audio output: conversion pipeline complete
02-15 20:03:48.485 3832-4671/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9b3bf128/123f] core audio resampler: looking for audio resampler module matching "any": 2 candidates
02-15 20:03:48.485 3832-4671/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9b3bf128/123f] core audio resampler: using audio resampler module "ugly"
02-15 20:03:48.485 3832-4647/tv.redtop D/VLC: [aa4b3508/1227] core input: Decoder wait done in 259 ms
02-15 20:03:48.707 3832-4671/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9b3bd8a8/123f] mpeg_audio decoder: frame too big 2509 > 2508 (emulated startcode ?)
02-15 20:03:48.708 3832-4671/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9b3bd8a8/123f] mpeg_audio decoder: emulated startcode
02-15 20:03:48.708 3832-4671/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9b3bd8a8/123f] mpeg_audio decoder: free bitrate mode
02-15 20:03:49.125 3832-4671/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9b3bdc28/123f] mpeg_audio packetizer: frame too big 2509 > 2508 (emulated startcode ?)
02-15 20:03:49.125 3832-4671/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9b3bdc28/123f] mpeg_audio packetizer: emulated startcode
02-15 20:03:49.125 3832-4671/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9b3bdc28/123f] mpeg_audio packetizer: free bitrate mode
02-15 20:03:49.543 3832-4671/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9b3bdc28/123f] mpeg_audio packetizer: frame too big 2509 > 2508 (emulated startcode ?)
02-15 20:03:49.961 3832-4671/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9b3bdc28/123f] mpeg_audio packetizer: emulated startcode
02-15 20:03:49.961 3832-4671/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9b3bdc28/123f] mpeg_audio packetizer: free bitrate mode
02-15 20:03:50.379 3832-4671/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9b3bdc28/123f] mpeg_audio packetizer: frame too big 2509 > 2508 (emulated startcode ?)
02-15 20:03:50.798 3832-4671/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9b3bdc28/123f] mpeg_audio packetizer: emulated startcode
02-15 20:03:50.936 3832-4671/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9b3bdc28/123f] mpeg_audio packetizer: emulated startcode (no startcode on following frame)
02-15 20:03:51.216 3832-4671/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9b3bdc28/123f] mpeg_audio packetizer: emulated startcode
02-15 20:03:51.216 3832-4671/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9b3bdc28/123f] mpeg_audio packetizer: free bitrate mode
02-15 20:03:51.772 3832-4671/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9b3bdc28/123f] mpeg_audio packetizer: frame too big 2509 > 2508 (emulated startcode ?)
02-15 20:03:51.773 3832-4671/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9b3bdc28/123f] mpeg_audio packetizer: emulated startcode
02-15 20:03:52.051 3832-4671/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9b3bdc28/123f] mpeg_audio packetizer: free bitrate mode
02-15 20:03:52.329 3832-4671/tv.redtop W/VLC: [98056fe8/123f] core audio output: buffer too late (-1691313 us): dropped
02-15 20:03:54.312 3832-4647/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9aec4128/1227] ts demux: PATCallBack called
02-15 20:03:54.312 3832-4647/tv.redtop W/VLC: [9aec4128/1227] ts demux: discontinuity received 0x0 instead of 0x2 (pid=257)
02-15 20:03:54.313 3832-4671/tv.redtop D/VLC: [9b3bdc28/123f] mpeg_audio packetizer: frame too big 2509 > 2508 (emulated startcode ?)
```

And it goes on repeating the same thing (I've removed reoccuring "emulated startcode logs). I believe that the audio streams that are facing problem are "mpeg_audio" where as the "mpeg4audio" works just fine in my player. But both works fine for the vlc media player. What am I doing wrong?